# Codename One LeftBarCommand Text Size not Changing

Tags: command, codenameone, font-size

In my application I am using a command added to the top left bar and I am trying to change the font size.

What is generally a simple task is causing quite a bit of labor and I still couldn't figure it out.

In the theme builder, I have tried to change the font size in the default settings (changes the color, but not the size) and accessing several component UIIDs, including Command, SideCommand, ToolBar and others, all to no avail.

Command also does not give give direct access to the styles.

How can I change the font size of the command? Is there a special UIID?

```
    Command left = new Command("Done") {            
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            confirmationDialog();
        }             
    };            

    tb.addCommandToLeftBar(left);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the command UIID by:

```
left.putClientProperty("uiid", "MyUIID");
```

In the case of title commands they have the UIID `TitleCommand`.

Comment: Many thanks ... TitleCommand did the trick. The command itself appears not to have a .put method, though. There is ..putClientProperty, but it seems not to work for setting the UIID..

Comment: Sorry that was a sleepless night blunder I meant `putClientProperty`. Fixed my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Sh... happens :-) .. no problem at all. Thanks for your time to look into this.